# Web scrape and pull an attribute value instead of the text value out of td for the entire table beautiful soup

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape some data from a table, but they have the content that I actually would like in an attribute.

Example xml:

'''

```
<tr data-row="0">
    <th scope ="row" class="left" data_append-csv="AlleRi00" data-stat="player" csk="Allen, Ricardo">
        <a href="/players/A/AlleRi00.htm">Ricardo Allen </a>
    </th>
    <td class="center poptip out dnp" data-stat="week_4" data-tip"Out: Concussion" csk= "4">
        <strong>O</strong>
    </td>
```

'''

When scraping the table I use the following code:

'''

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/atl/2017_injuries.htm'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'sortable', 'id': 'team_injuries'})
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

final_data = []
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all(['th','td'])
    row = [tr.text for tr in td]
    final_data.append(row)
df = pd.DataFrame(final_data[1:],final_data[0])
```

'''

With my current code, I get a good looking dataframe with headers and all the info that is visible when looking at the table. However, I would like to get "Out: Concussion" instead of "O" within the table. I've been trying numerous ways and cannot figure it out. Please let me know if this is possible with the current process or if I am approaching it all wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/atl/2017_injuries.htm'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'sortable', 'id': 'team_injuries'})
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

final_data = []
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all(['th','td'])
    row = [tr['data-tip'] if tr.has_attr("data-tip") else tr.text for tr in td]

    final_data.append(row)

m = final_data[1:]
final_dataa = [[m[j][i] for j in range(len(m))] for i in range(len(m[0]))]

df = pd.DataFrame(final_dataa,final_data[0]).T

df.to_csv("D:\\injuries.csv", index = False)
```

Screenshot of `csv` file (I've done some formatting so that it looks neat):

[image]

Comment: Because it doesn't give me the information I want. I am looking to pull the attribute not the text out of <td>.

Comment: That's huge! I can't believe I missed just a minor step like that. Thank you!!